# Combining many if conditions in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Just wondering, any better way to write this:

```
if key != "a" && key != "b" && key != "c"
  ...
end
```

Perhaps concatenating the conditions above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
unless %w(a b c).include?(key)
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 5):

```
unless ["a", "b", "c"].include?(key)
    # ...
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
case key
when "a", "b", "c"
else
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [Array#include](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
if not ["a", "b", "c"].include? key
  ...
```

A bit more concise.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use include:

```
if !%w(a b c).include?(key) then
  ...
end
```

Comment: Using `if !` is the same as `unless`, but `unless` results in more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

```
if %w( a b c ).exclude?(key)
  ...
end
```

from `active_support`

Comment: If you're going to recommend Active Support for a question that doesn't have a Rails tag, it'd be very useful to the OP to describe [how to cherry-pick ONLY the method needed](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html), instead of loading ALL of Active Support just for one method.

Answer (score 0):

```
unless key[/[abc]/]
  ...
end
```

...but I prefer sawa's answer for readability.